# Why it's surveys not surveies?

Tags: plural-forms, spelling

Sometimes I need to change `y` to `ies` but for `survey`, it's not. So far as I know there are some other cases too.

Is there any "formula" I can follow for the plural form of words with `-y`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing half of the rule.

Yes, you change -y to -ies but **only if the letter preceding the y is a consonant**.

If the word ends in a vowel plus -y, [you just add an s](https://howtospell.co.uk/y-to-ies-or-s-plural-rule).

> a. If the word ends in a vowel (a,e,i,o,u) + y then just add s
>   boy - boys, journey - journeys, key - keys, tray - trays, donkey - donkeys... Or we'd have too many vowels and a confusing word (key - keies)!!!

Comment: is this a solid rule? no exceptions at all?

Comment: This is English -- There's always an exception.  In British "bogey" is a piece of nasal mucus, plural bogies.